# How to find the sum of a single row in 2D array

Tags: c#

Working on a project for school where I need to create a value returning method that loops through an array and adds up values in a single row and returns the sum. I am very new to coding as this is my first course. I have made the array already and have values stored in it. Just cannot figure out how to code the method to loop through it. Here is the coded array:

```
 double[,] SalesArray = new double[2, 7];
```

Here is what i have tried already. DRINK_ROW is a constant initialized with 1 as thats the row that holds user input for those sales. weekdrinksales is the variable i declared to hold the sum of this row. I am getting an "index was outside the bounds of the array" error.

```
 private double findDrinkSum()
        {
            for(int index =0; index < SalesArray.Length; index++)
            {
                WeekDrinkSales += SalesArray[DRINK_ROW, index];


            }

            return WeekDrinkSales;
        }
```

Comment: You've shown what you've tried, but it would also help if you explain _why_ that code doesn't work. You _should_ be getting an exception with this code. In addition, it would help to debug your program an inspect the value of `SalesArray.Length` which might give you a clue to why that's not correct.

Comment: You've even spelled out it is homework. On SO nobody wants to do homework for anyone but themselves. But I want to help out a bit. You wrote: `index was outside the bounds of the array`, what does that tell you and where does it occur?

Comment: @CS1061 there's nothing wrong with asking a question about homework, as long as it shows what you're trying to do, what you've attempted to solve the problem, and explains why it doesn't work. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822

Comment: @gunr2171 & Cabe My misunderstanding, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't already your problem, see it code. So you can calculate sum of array, there is a method GetLength(int value), where if value=0, then method returns a number of to row, and if value=1, then returns a number of to columns.

To answer your problem, the Lenght property returns the number of elements of the entire array, not a row or a column.

I suggest you make the constant DRINK_ROW in the method the accepted value in the method, and just insert it in the code.This way the method will be more universal.

```
private double FindDrinkSum()
{ 
     //if you didn't this variable as a field of something class
     double WeekDrinkSales=0; 
     for(int index=0; i< SalesArray.GetLength(1);i++)
     {
       WeekDrinkSales+=SalesArray[DRINK_ROW,index];
     }
  return WeekDrinkSales;
}
```

I suggest you make the constant DRINK_ROW in the method the accepted value in the method, and just insert it in the code.This way the method will be more universal.